# MS ReportViewer limiting the number of rows so there is no vertical scrolling

Tags: wpf, mvvm, reportviewer

We are using the .net reportview control and creating RDLC templates to display reports in our application. The output just seems to guess where to add pagebreaks and as such the user has to scroll to see more rows. Is there a way to make it add a break before the end of the visible viewing area so that all the rows show up on screen and a break is added?

All of this is being done using WPF and MVVM.

Comment: I can't understand the question, do you want the same No. of pages regardless the No. of rows ? , because what you are describing is a normal behaviour for me

Comment: I want all the rows to show up on a single page at 100%. I want to limit the number of rows based on the size of the control that is displaying the report without scrolling vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rectangle Component change `PageBreak` property to your preference.